# Get related data except other data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Word has a self join table, and `word1 is related with word2, word3, word4`
`project1 has many words` and contains the words `project1 has: word1, word2`

How can I get all the related `words` for a `word1` except those which have already been assigned to project1, in this case 'word2'

Expected output for `word1: word3, word4` (below is what I have done, is there a better solution?)

```
related = project.words.where(id: self.related_words.map(&:id)).map(&:id)
self.related_words.where.not(id: related)
```

Comment: Does your current solution work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your current solution works I would improve it using `pluck`

```
related = project.words.where(id: self.related_words.pluck(:id)).pluck(:id)
self.related_words.where.not(id: related)
```

Why? Because `pluck` works as a DB query and is therefore faster compared to Ruby `map`, see docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck